# How can we check whether the user input equal to one elements of an array?

Tags: bash

Imagine we have an array like this:

```bsh
declare -a array=( "one" "two" "three" "four" "five" )

for i in "${all[@]}"; do
        echo "$i"
done
```

And we can give an input from the user like this:

```
read -p "Enter a number: " number
```

I need something to check if the user input matches one of the elements of this array. If not, this should run:

```
echo "Try again: "
```

This process should be repeated until the user input matches to one of the array elements.

Comment: Is this a homework project?

Comment: No. I just tried many ways but as I'm new learner I did not find a good way.

Comment: this reads very similar to a homwork problem... What have you tried so far? Have you gotten any errors? Or are you just asking for a handout?

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/filters/169 might be a better place for this question if its not about Ubuntu.

Comment: I used it but doesn't work

Comment: please post all that in the original post, and make sure to format it. Also I would strongly suggest following Graham's suggestion as you won't get much help here

Comment: I suspect the question will be moved to SO rather smartly.  There are plenty of resources dealing with accessing arrays. Only a matter of the time taken to read. So it does sound like homework rather than leisure.

Comment: This question is perfectly on-topic here. [Please do not close questions as off-topic](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13807/are-bash-shell-scripting-questions-on-topic) just because they're about bash. We have a lot of users who are able to help with Bash questions. I would even argue that these questions would be better received here on Ask Ubuntu and on Unix & Linux!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to loop over the array to check whether a value belongs to it. Also, in this case I would use a recursive call of a function instead of another loop. As I understand correctly you are searching for something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=( "one" "two" "three" "four" "five" )

function get_input() {
    read -p "${1}: " number
    if [[ " ${array[*]} " == *" ${number} "* ]]
    then
        echo 'true';
    else
        get_input 'Try again'   # a recursive call of the function
    fi
}

get_input 'Enter a number'      # the initial call of the function
```

With the `[[` [test](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) command we searing for exact match `==` between one string (the left side) and one regular expression (the right side).

- The expression `" ${array[*]} "` will expand our array as a string, surrounded by two spaces, thus each *element* (even the first and the last) will be surrounded by spaces - try `echo '^'" ${array[*]} "'$'`.
- The regular expression `*" ${number} "*` will match to any strung that consist of the value of the variable `$number`, surrounded by spaces, surrounded by no mater what other characters `*`.

We can perform such test by some other tools like `grep` (with suppressed stdout `-q`, and searching for exact match `\<...\>`). Here is one funny version:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=( "one" "two" "three" "four" "five" )

function get_input() {
    read -p "${1}: " nm
    echo "${array[*]}" | grep -q "\<${nm}\>" && echo 'true' || get_input 'Try again'
}

get_input "Enter a number"
```

> If we want to call the corresponding number of each element in the
>   array instead of inserting the words like ''one'' or ''two'', what can
>   we do? for example: Enter the number: 2

```
#!/bin/bash

array=( "one" "two" "three" "four" "five" )

# Get the lenght of the array
array_lenght="${#array[*]}"

function get_input() {
    read -p "${1}: " number

    # Test whether the variable $number has a value &and&
    # test whether as integer this value is less or equal to the $array_lenght
    if [[ ! -z ${number} ]] && (( number <= array_lenght && number > 0 ))
    then
        # Outpit the value of the cerain array element
        # Note the first array element has number 0
        echo "${array[$(( number - 1 ))]}"
    else
        get_input 'Try again'
    fi
}

get_input 'Enter an integer number'
```

Comment: this will get you a clear look ```[[ " ${array[*]} " =~ " ${number} " ]]```

Comment: If we want to call the corresponding number of each element in the array instead of inserting the words like ''one'' or ''two'', what can we do?

for example: 
Enter the number: 2

Comment: Hi, @msndm, the question is updated.

Answer (score 5):

You can make the array into an associative array instead.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A array=([one]=1 [two]=1 [tree]=1 [four]=1 [five]=1)

m="Guess? "

while true; do   
    read -r -p "$m" i
    [[ ${array[$i]} == 1 ]] && break || m="Guess again? "
done  

echo "Good guess!"
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably all the other answers are more efficient than this one, but I think that this is more beginner-friendly:

```bsh
declare -a all=( "one" "two" "three" "four" "five" )

read -p "Enter a number: " number

while true; do

    for i in "${all[@]}"; do
        if [[ "$number" = "$i" ]]; then
            exit 0
        fi
    done

    read -p "Try again: " number

done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a array=("one" "two" "three" "four" "five")

number="wrong"

while [[ ! "${array[@]}" =~ "${number}" ]]; do
  [[ "${number}" != "wrong" ]] && echo "Incorrect"
  read -p "Insert number: " number
done
```